# Oracle - Stored Procedure. Update Table, with Table name according to arguments

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

So I have a Store Procedure for Updating a certain table with the name of the table is according to arguments `v_example` inputed.

```
PROCEDURE update_name(example_id NUMBER, v_example VARCHAR2, lcursor out rcursor)
AS
v_sequel VARCHAR2(10000);
Begin
    UPDATE T_EXAMPLE_'||v_example||'_L1 SET T_EXAMPLE_'||v_example||'_L1.SUM1 = (SELECT T_SDEXAMP_'||v_example||'.SUM1
                                                        FROM T_SDEXAMP_'||v_example||'
                                                        WHERE T_SDEXAMP_'||v_example||'.BILATERAL_ID = T_EXAMPLE_'||v_example||'_L1.BILATERAL_ID),
                              T_EXAMPLE_'||v_example||'_L1.SUM2 = (SELECT T_SDEXAMP_'||v_example||'.SUM2
                                                        FROM T_SDEXAMP_'||v_example||'
                                                        WHERE T_SDEXAMP_'||v_example||'.BILATERAL_ID = T_EXAMPLE_'||v_example||'_L1.BILATERAL_ID),
                              T_EXAMPLE_'||v_example||'_L1.SUM3 = (SELECT T_SDEXAMP_'||v_example||'.SUM3
                                                        FROM T_SDEXAMP_'||v_example||'
                                                        WHERE T_SDEXAMP_'||v_example||'.BILATERAL_ID = T_EXAMPLE_'||v_example||'_L1.BILATERAL_ID)
    WHERE T_EXAMPLE_'||v_example||'_L1.BILATERAL_ID = '||example_id||';
    COMMIT;
End;
```

So, as you can see, I want the table name to be a **Combination** of T_EXAMPLE_, the arguments v_example, and _L1...

When I execute the above script, it gaves me this error:

`ERROR line 1076, col 18, ending_line 1076, ending_col 32, Found ''||v_example||'', Invalid identifier: '||v_example||'`

Can someone help me? Thanks....

Comment: I don't believe the error is for this query.  The issue is v_service, but it doesn't appear anywhere in your code.

Comment: ahh sorry sorry, I gave a wrong error, that v_service is before edited to v_example....

Comment: You talk about updating a particular database.  Do you really mean that you are trying to update a particular table?  Or am I not understanding something?  Also, your procedure declares an `OUT` parameter but your code isn't opening a cursor.  What query do you want to run to open the cursor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In static SQL defined in an procedure, the identifiers (table names, column names) must be defined and available at compile time.

To achieve what it looks like you are trying to achieve... dynamically specifying the table name in a SQL statement, you would have to use some form of "dynamic SQL".

The old-school way of doing that in an Oracle procedure is to use the `DBMS_SQL` package. Later, Oracle introduced `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. And after that, Oracle added `CURSOR FOR` syntax. There's probably even newer ways to do it.

There is similarity in the pattern to all of those. I'm not going to write it all for you, or repeat the information available in Oracle documentation.

Here's an example of what EXECUTE IMMEDIATE might look like. Dynamically create your SQL string, to make all of the identifiers (column names, table_names, functions, etc.) part of the static SQL text. And use bind placeholders for values you want to pass in.

```
... PROCEDURE doit2it(v_id INT, v_example VARCHAR, ... )
AS 
   v_sql  VARCHAR(1023);
BEGIN
   v_sql := 'T_EXAMPLE_'||v_example||'_L1' 
         || ' SET T_EXAMPLE_'||v_example||'_L1.SUM1 = '
         || ' ...'
         || ' WHERE col = :b1 ';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql USING v_id ;
```

Again, `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` isn't the only mechanism for executing dynamic SQL, but it's a lot cleaner looking code than using the `DBMS_SQL` package.

Since the text of the SQL statement is in a string, you can use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE to output the SQL text before it's executed, which can help in debugging.

**FOLLOWUP**

In the example, the value of `v_id` is passed in to the execution of the SQL statement, supplied as a value for the bind placeholder `:b1`.

If you have two placeholders in the SQL, you'd pass in two values, e.g.

```
  USING v_id, v_name
```

Since the binds are positional (and not by name), I tend to use `:b1`, `:b2`, `:b3`, etc for the placeholders in the SQL text. But I think you can use any name that is valid. The "nameless" numbering of the bind placeholders helps remind me that it's *by position*, not by name. If I needed to pass in the same value twice, I'd use distinct names for the bind placeholders and supply the value twice, e.g.

```
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '... foo = :b1 AND bar = :b2 ...' USING v_id, v_id;
```

That pattern of using bind placeholders and passing in values is similar to what happens "behind the scenes" (as it were) with *static* SQL in PL/SQL block that references PL/SQL variables. For example:

```
  v_name VARCHAR(30) := 'douglas adams' ;
  v_id   INT         := 42 ;
  UPDATE mytable SET myname = v_name WHERE myid = v_id ;
```

When the PL/SQL is compiled, the SQL statement is checked, and it gets converted into SQL text something like this:

```
  UPDATE mytable SET myname = :b1 WHERE myid = :b2
```

And at execution time, the value of `v_name` and `v_id` are supplied for the bind placeholders. Similar to what we're doing in the dynamic SQL example.

Comment: so, the v_id doesn't used directly to the Where statement, instead it used in the USING and bind the v_id to :b1 ??? Btw, your code worked perfectly, thanks :)

Comment: "If the dynamic SQL statement does not represent an anonymous PL/SQL block or a CALL statement, ... placeholders are associated with bind variables in the USING clause by position, not by name." For dyanmic SQL for an anonymous PL/SQL block or a CALL, the names of the bind placeholders are significant if they are repeated. Reference: [http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011)

Answer (score 1):

You statement seems to be wrong, I think you can make it sorter:

```
v_sql := 'UPDATE T_EXAMPLE_'||v_example||'_L1 SET 
    (SUM1, SUM2, SUM3) = 
        (SELECT SUM1, SUM2, SUM3 
        FROM T_SDEXAMP_'||v_example||'
        WHERE T_SDEXAMP_'||v_example||'.BILATERAL_ID = T_EXAMPLE_'||v_example||'_L1.BILATERAL_ID)
WHERE BILATERAL_ID = :excample_id';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql USING example_id;
```

Call `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql);` before (or instead of) the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` in order to verify the update statement.

Comment: Thanks Wernfried , it has been answered before by @spencer7593 and it's correct, but really thanks Wernfried.. :)